# In Tensorflow, how to pass in image with 3 channels to a convolutional neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to fit an image with 3 channels into tensorflow 2.0 and getting datatype error

```
TensorFlow TypeError: Value passed to parameter input has DataType uint8 not in list of allowed values: float16, float32
```

This is my model:

```
def conv_block(number_of_filters, kernel_size, strides=(1, 1), padding='SAME', activation=tf.nn.relu):
    return tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
        filters=number_of_filters, 
        kernel_size=kernel_size, 
        strides=strides, 
        padding=padding, 
        activation=activation)

class ImageSearchModel(object):
    def __init__(self, learning_rate, image_size, number_of_classes):
        tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()
        
        model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
        
        #convolutional layers
        model.add(conv_block(number_of_filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3)))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='SAME'))
        model.add(conv_block(number_of_filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3)))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='SAME'))
        model.add(conv_block(number_of_filters=256, kernel_size=(5,5)))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='SAME'))
        model.add(conv_block(number_of_filters=512, kernel_size=(5,5)))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='SAME'))
        
        #flattening
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
        
        #dense
        model.add(dense_block(units=128))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))
        model.add(dense_block(units=256))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))
        model.add(dense_block(units=512))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))
        model.add(dense_block(units=1024))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))
        
        #output
        model.add(dense_block(units=number_of_classes, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
        
        # compile the model
        model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
        
        self.model = model
        
    def Train(self, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):

        for i, s in enumerate(X_train):
            X_train[i] = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(s, dtype=tf.float16)
        for i, s in enumerate(X_test):
            X_test[i] = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(s, dtype=tf.float16)
        self.model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=32, verbose=0)
        loss, acc = self.model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
        print('Test Accuracy: %.3f' % acc)
```

This is my caller:

```
print(f"There are {len(classes)} classes: {classes}")
model = ImageSearchModel(0.001, (32, 32), len(classes))
model.Train(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)
```

This is my image processing:

```
def image_loader(image_path, image_size):
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = cv2.resize(image, image_size, cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    return image

def dataset_preprocessing(dataset_path, image_size):
    images = []
    labels = []
    image_paths = []
    
    for image_name in os.listdir(dataset_path):
        label = image_name.split(".")[0]
        label = label.split("_", 2)[1]
        image_path = os.path.join(dataset_path, image_name)
        images.append(image_loader(image_path, image_size))
        image_paths.append(image_path)
        labels.append(label)
        
    classes = unique(labels)
    assert len(images) == len(labels), f"{len(images)} != {len(labels)}"
    return np.array(images), np.array(labels), np.array(classes)
```

This is what my input look like:

[image]

How do I fit the 3 channels into the CNN correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You're very close: you need to divide your integer values by 256 (2^8 from `uint8`) to get the expected float values.  `float16` should be plenty of precision to give you a useful model training.

Comment: It's rather dividing by `255` (uint8 max value) if we want to scale correctly the pixel values between 0 and 1.

Comment: That depends on your given range.  Since we're trying to convert directly to another binary form, dividing by 256 gives a much cleaner translation of the value.

Comment: That's not that big of a deal in any case, but the fact that the data will not be scaled optimally (off by 1/256) should be more of a concern in regard to the learning process. [We typically rescale pixel values by 255](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/Rescaling).

Comment: Where do I do this?  Sorry can you write it into code?  I tried using convert_image_dtype but it doesn't seem to work.  I think I am just not very familiar with the syntax, updated my code to reflect this.

Comment: @BillSoftwareEngineer Is it cifar-10?

Comment: Yes it is, online tutorial

Comment: @WholeBrain: "typically" is merely because the cited example applies the canonical continuous normalizing.  It is *not* universally optimal, especially when converting to a discrete representation, and certainly not at the expense of an exact translation.

Comment: @Prune We include the `1.` so that we don't undermine the model's convergence. That's a [convention](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/data_types.html#input-types) that float images include it. I believe that preserving the translation exactitude is not a concern for the learning purpose.

Comment: You're welcome to use whatever conventions and heuristics you want.  I'll stick with our empirical results.  Cutting out `1.` does not harm our models' convergences at all -- I don't know what sort of model you're using that is sensitive to the range.  What I do know is that when my group employ the full acceleration stack, the direct 0-255 mapping is faster and more accurate than dividing by 256.  We track this to the more accurate value mapping in the image-processing domain.